# delimiting carat A in python

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

#### I have data in form:

```
37101000ssd48800^A1420asd938987^A2011-09-10^A18:47:50.000^A99.00^A1^A0^A
37101000sd48801^A44557asd03082^A2011-09-06^A13:24:58.000^A42.01^A1^A0^A
```

So first I took it literally and tried:

```
line = line.split("^A")
```

and also

```
line = line.split("\\u001")
```

#### So, the issue is:

The first approach works on my local machine if I do this:

```
cat input.txt | python mapper.py
```

It runs fine locally (input.txt is the above data), but fails on hadoop streaming clusters.

Someone told me that I should use `"\\u001"` as the delimiter, but this is also not working, either on my local machine or on clusters.

#### For hadoop folks:

If I debug it on local using:

```
cat input.txt | python mapper.py | sort | python reducer.py
```

This runs  just fine, if I use `"^A"` as delimiter on local but I am getting errors when running on clusters, and the error code is not too helpful either...

Any suggestions on how can i debug this?
Thanks

Comment: Try `\x53`. That should be the same as ^

Comment: This isn't clear from your question: is the delimiter a control-A that's being printed as `^A` in whatever you're using to list your data, or is it actually a caret followed by an `A`? If it's the former, you want `line.split('\u001')` (the extra backslash is why it doesn't work for you). If it's the latter, `line.split('^A')`.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto: Under exactly what circumstances would you expect `'\x53'` to work when `'^'` didn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the original data uses a control-A as a delimiter, and it's just being printed as `^A` in whatever you're using to list the data, you have two choices:

1. Pipe whatever you use the list the data into a Python script that uses `split('^A')`.
2. Just use `split('\u001')` to split on actual control-A values.

The latter is almost always going to be what you really want. The reason this didn't work from you is that you wrote `split('\\u001')`, escaping the backslash, so you're splitting on the literal string `\u001` rather than on control-A.

If the original data actually has `^A` (a caret followed by an `A`) as the delimiter, just use `split('^A')`.