# How to Specify ToDate during Schema Definition?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I load my files and generate dates for them in two steps:

```
A = LOAD 'foo.txt' USING PigStorage('\\u001') AS (
    bar:chararray
    ,baz:int
);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE
    ToDate(bar, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS bar
    ,baz
;
```

How can I do it in one step?

The following throws an error (`mismatched input '(' expecting RIGHT_PARAN`:

```
A = LOAD 'foo.txt' USING PigStorage('\\u001') AS (
    ToDate(bar:chararray, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS bar
    ,baz:int
);
```

or

```
A = LOAD 'foo.txt' USING PigStorage('\\u001') AS (
    ToDate($0, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS bar
    ,baz:int
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDFs can't be applied in the schema definition. You may write your [own loader](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/udf.html#load-store-functions) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `^A` instead of `\\u001`. For more information, use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462006/delimiting-carat-a-in-python).

Comment: The question was not about delimiting but applying ToDate